# CFGrid boolean columns submitting empty strings

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfgrid, cfgridcolumn

I have a table with 5 boolean columns, I am using HTML format CFGrid to view and edit the data, however when a user submits a new row the boolean fields all submit with empty strings, regardless of state (checked or not),  when I switch the format to applet, it works fine, the values come as 1 or 0.  I am forced to use the HTML, one of the requirements is that IPads be able to use the app.

I know I am doing something wrong I just can't figure out what

Code for the grid:

```
    <cfgrid name="taskgrid" query="getTasks" selectmode="edit" insert="yes" striperows="yes" insertbutton="Add Entry" delete="yes" deletebutton="Delete Entry" colheaders="yes" format="html" width="945" height="300"  >
            <cfgridcolumn name="ID" display="no" >
            <cfgridcolumn name="UserID" display="no" >
            <cfgridcolumn name="TaskDate" header="Date" type="string_noCase" width="100">
            <cfgridcolumn name="TaskStart" header="Start" mask="L:NN" width="55">
            <cfgridcolumn name="TaskEnd" header="End" mask="L:NN" width="55">
            <cfgridcolumn name="TaskDesc" header="Description of Task" width="450">
            <cfgridcolumn name="TaskTotalTime" header="Total Min" width="65">
            <cfgridcolumn name="BIL" header="Bil" width="35">
            <cfgridcolumn name="BEA" header="BEA" width="35">
            <cfgridcolumn name="TOne" header="T1" width="35">
            <cfgridcolumn name="LAP" header="LAP" width="35">
            <cfgridcolumn name="MIG" header="Mig" width="35">
        </cfgrid>
```

the query is a simple select * from table, I am using a loop to process the grid on the action page with the proper variables, everything but the checkboxes/booleans is working.  Any suggestions of a fix or hint of where I am going wrong?

Thanks
MP

Comment: Perhaps you could use a variation from one of the answers posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884474/cfgrid-boolean-column-as-yes-no

Comment: I did try Steve's method, I used "True/False" instead of yes/no and same thing, boolean types are passing empty to the form handler.